# How to set up a DNS to use a catch-all address?

Tags: .htaccess, domain-name-system, wildcard-subdomain, subdomain

This is not really a programming question, it's more about settings that I can alter visually.

I have bought a domain and am wondering how I can get it work in such a way that everything before the .example.com except for things I've already set (like pop.example.com) are being forwarded to www.example.com (or *.example.com).

so stuff like this:

- pop.example.com
- ftp.example.com
- my.example.com

Goes to the appropriate URL, but:

- idontknowwhattheurlwas.example.com
- ivemistypedsomething.example.com
- bla.example.com
- 123.example.com

Are aliases for www.example.com.

The options for adding a rule inside the DNS configuration are:

- A
- AAAA
- MX
- TXT
- CNAME
- SRV

Or perhaps it's better to do this with .htaccess? and if so, how should i configure it?

Comment: This is probably better asked at http://serverfault.com/, but do you have access to the zone file? Wild card DNS is easy to set up if you can edit the zone file directly.

Comment: I've only got access to a control panel with visual tweaking of the DNS and the top-level .htaccess

Comment: I think the dupe question has a clearer answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/175225/how-to-set-up-a-dns-to-use-a-catch-all-address/175239#175239. Perhaps the two questions could be merged? They are, after all, exactly the same question, word for word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need both:

In DNS zone setup an entry (the last, the best)

```
*.your_domain.foo.  IN  A   999.999.999.999 # correct this csi-like ip
```

The last dot in domain is very important.

That will match any.your_domain.foo to your IP. you can place other entries for other subdomains / ip's before.

And in apache / other web server you mus setup a vhost or something to handle all the requests an set ServerAlias / ServerName to

```
ServerAlias *.your_domain.foo
```

Again place this Vhost the lasts, defining any existing vhosts in your_domain.foo before the default one.

Apache loads config files using an ascii ordered scheme so put this in a `099_default` file and prepend other by `050_`

In your case, the DNS should let you to use a `*.yourdomain.foo.` in zone definition and I think you can archieve the apache part using mod_rewrite, if it is enabled. I think that There are some ways of simulate virtual hosting usin rewrites with the `SERVER_NAME` variable as a condition. Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.3/rewrite/vhosts.html. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3):

You do this in DNS. If you have a sane (bind-like) dns server you want to add something like this to the configuration for your zone:

```
server.example.com.  A      192.168.1.1
*.example.com.       CNAME  server.example.com.
```

It creates an alias for the wildcard and points it to the address of the server.You can also do it directly:

```
*.example.com.       A      192.168.1.1
```

But for management reasons the first solution is typically better. Once this is done you create a catch-all vhost that mirrors your www.example.com host.

Answer (score 0):

Use a star:

*.example.com     CNAME     www.example.com
www.example.com   A         192.168.1.5

Answer (score 0):

It's named jocker. In your DNS configuration put all the names you want and then add the line

```
* CNAME www.example.com
```

All the unknown names will be CNAMED to www.example.com